# I know PV=nRT but that's total what about partial?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the formula for finding the partial pressure ? 
I know PV=nRT but that's total what about partial ?

Comment: From Wikipedia: `In a mixture of gases, each gas has a partial pressure which is the hypothetical pressure of that gas if it alone occupied the volume of the mixture at the same temperature.` Thus, for a mixture of (ideal) gases you get an equivalent equation for gas $i$ with partial pressure $p_{i}$ and amount $n_{i}$: $p_{i} V = n_{i} R T$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too simple (but I'm not sure whether it is covered by homework).

Comment: @Jan I don't think we should close something for being 'too simple'. That sounds very condescending.

Comment: @bon You’re right and I probably should have let someone else do the judgement. I apologise.

Answer (score 1):

To find partial pressures of a mixture of non-reactive gases, you can use [Dalton's Law of partial pressures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton's_law).

If you know the total pressure of the mixture and the number of moles of each gas, you can find the pressure of each gas by multiplying its mole fraction with the total pressure.

Answer (score 0):

By **Dalton's law of partial pressure** (any high school chem textbook will have this law), the partial pressure of a single gas in a mixture of non-reactive (or relatively inert gases) is directly proportional to its mole fraction in the mixture, with the constant of proportionality being the P in PV=nRT (i.e., the total pressure of the system)

[image]